# Keep ActionBar from reverting changes

Tags: android, android-actionbar, orientation, android-manifest

I'm using an activity with a webview and to keep it from refreshing whenever the device is rotated, I have `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` in AndroidManifest.xml. The problem is that whenever the device is rotated, the changes I have made to the status bar dissapear. Does anyone know how to keep the webview from refreshing whenever rotated AND keep the changes I've made in the status bar?

This is the method that I use to make the changes to the statusbar

```
public static void changeActionBarFont(Activity activity) {
        Typeface slab = Typeface.createFromAsset(activity.getAssets(),
                "RobotoSlab.ttf");
        int actionBarTitle = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier(
                "action_bar_title", "id", "android");
        int actionBarSubTitle = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier(
                "action_bar_subtitle", "id", "android");
        if (0 == actionBarTitle & 0 == actionBarSubTitle) {
            actionBarTitle = com.actionbarsherlock.R.id.abs__action_bar_title;
            actionBarSubTitle = com.actionbarsherlock.R.id.abs__action_bar_subtitle;
        }
        TextView title = (TextView) activity.getWindow().findViewById(
                actionBarTitle);
        TextView subtitle = (TextView) activity.getWindow().findViewById(
                actionBarSubTitle);
        if (title != null | subtitle != null) {
            title.setTypeface(slab);
            subtitle.setTypeface(slab);
            subtitle.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFFFF"));
        }
    }
```

**Edit:** Removeing the `configChanges` from the `AndroidManifest` does in fact fix the problem with the `ActionBar`, but I need them to keep the `webview` from reloading whenever the device is rotated. Anyone have any ideas as to how I can keep them both?

Answer (score 0):

It may not be what you want to hear right now, but it is better to try to recreate the layout in the new orientation, rather than just preventing the orientation change.

In your onCreate check whether there is a saved instance (as a result of the orientation change) e.g.

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
  //recreate the current state
}
else {
  //normal start
}
```

You might need to retain some values (either in Shared Prefs or onSavedInstanceState).

This approach is more difficult than locking the orientation, but it is a better approach in the long run and is well worth the investment (extra effort).